# Unpredictable integer overflow with ksort

Tags: php, linux, sorting, integer-overflow

After making a fix to my PHP application on my test server, I pushed it to my production server and the fix didn't work. After tracking it down I found that ksort() was causing index keys to overflow for integers larger than the max 32-bit signed value (2147483648) on my production server only. On my test server it would only overflow for integers larger than the max signed 64-bit integer (9223372036854775808).

Both servers (as fully as I can tell) have the same software configuration

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Kernel version: Linux version 3.0.0-15-generic-pae
- PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2

  1. CPU on production: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 910
  2. CPU on test server: AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 620

To reproduce this issue

```
$arr = array(2147483648 => 1, 5 => 2); ksort($arr); print_r($arr);
```

Outputs the following on my production server:

```
Array
(
    [-2147483648] => 1
    [5] => 2
)
```

The exact same code outputs the following on my test server:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 2
    [2147483648] => 1
)
```

I'm trying to figure out what could be causing this. Where should I be looking to narrow down why the servers have different integer sizes. Is it possible that I may have a different version of PHP (even though both appear to be the same) that was compiled with 32bit integers?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: What does "uname -m" reveal on each machine? Is your production server running a 32 bit kernel vs your test server running a 64 bit kernel?

Comment: Sorry, I added my actual question at the end. The output from "uname -m" is x86_64 on both servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at `PHP_INT_SIZE`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

> Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

I would also suggest to increase PHP `memory_limit` in php.ini or with `ini_set()`.

Comment: I'm getting a value of 8 on my production server and 4 on my live server. I thought that this was determined by the architecture of the server, why would two identical 64-bit operating systems have two different integer sizes?

Comment: I think the problem in within PHP set up. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php try to increase `PHP_INT_MAX`

Comment: I'll try reinstalling PHP on both servers to see if that remedies the problem. There is no way to modify the predefined constant PHP_INT_MAX via configuration files so far as I can tell.